# How to get assembly's processor architecture with .net 7+ from the running assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-7.0

Until .net 6 I couldl get the processor architecture (eg., MSIL, Amd64) of the current assembly with:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().ProcessorArchitecture
```

But is [obsolete since .net7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyname.processorarchitecture?view=net-7.0).

It was [suggested to use something from the namespace `System.Reflection.Metadata`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/59061#issuecomment-922392861).
However it's not clear how to get `ProcessorArchitecture`.

How to get this piece of information ? preferably without having to give an assembly name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this from the `Module` information, which represents the actual DLL. It has a `GetPEKind` function which returns information on which architecture it is compiled for.

```cs
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Modules.First().GetPEKind(out var pekind, out var machine);
Console.WriteLine(pekind);
Console.WriteLine(machine);
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/U8LrlZ)

Note that theoretically an assembly can have multiple modules, although this is unusual.

Comment: This solution is also much faster than that which reads the file (sub ms vs 2-3ms).

Answer (score 1):

Something similar is from PE file header,

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection.PortableExecutable;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using var fs = new FileStream(@"Example.dll", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            using var peReader = new PEReader(fs);
            Machine machine = peReader.PEHeaders.CoffHeader.Machine;
            Console.WriteLine(machine);
        }
    }
}
```

The values of `Machine` can be found in [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.portableexecutable.machine?view=net-7.0).